# If for Exception

Tags: python, if-statement, exception

I am teaching myself python and I am still an amateur at remembering all the keywords.

So; simple question, is there to way to use an `if` statement for an exception?

I can make the `exception(NameError)` print something.  However, I want to use an `if` statement for *if the exception is executed, then do this*.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear right now. Does a `try`-`except` block do what you intend?

Comment: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/error-handling/python-try-and-except/ this helps?

Comment: yes, I have a try-except block. I am just wondering if there is a way to address the exception in a if statement

Comment: You ask "if the exception is executed, then do this". Does a `try`-`except` block not accomplish this? Also, exceptions are raised, not "executed".

Comment: You can TRY: But answer would be No!  EXCEPT: this logically functions the same way, if this exception is caught then do execute this block. :p

Comment: Haramoz, I appreciate that url. Tomothy32, that's what I thought. The code is for face tracking; it only works if a face is initially detected because it will only track is a region of interest is found (the region of interest will always be located around the face), if the region is not found, then a nameerror occurs indicating that the area was not found. I already have the code 'try' the main function, and print "not found" when 'excepting' the nameerror. I want it to go back to the main function if the exception is made.

Comment: @GareBear If you want it to go back to normal execution, just move the rest of the code to after the try-except block...

Comment: If would help to provide an example of what you're looking for even if it's just pseudo-code.

Answer (score 1):

try-except blocks were designed *specifically* for the purpose of catching exceptions. if statements are conditionals and are not designed to work with exceptions.

Here's a simple program to demonstrate exception handling:

```
class SomeException(Exception):
    pass

try:
    print("In try block.")
    raise SomeException()
except SomeException:
    print("In except block.")
```

Additionally, if you need information about the exception, you can use a special except block:

```
class SomeException(Exception):
    pass

try:
    print("In try block.")
    raise SomeException()
except SomeException as exc: #exc is the exception object
    print("In except block.")
```

When creating exceptions, you can optionally pass one or more arguments to indicate *why* the exception was raised:

```
class SomeException(Exception):
    pass

try:
    print("In try block.")
    raise SomeException("message")
except SomeException as exc:
    print(exc.args[0]) #Prints "message"
```

Here's a [tutorial on exceptions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_exceptions.htm) that I found particularly useful.

Answer (score 0):

A "try-except" block is exactly what you're looking for. Any code in the "try" part is executed normally, but if there's an exception, instead of returning back, it goes to the "except" block.

**To phrase it how you were asking, any code in an "except" block runs IF the specific exception was raised/excecuted.**

Instead of an error like this:

```
print(x)

NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

You could do this:

```
try:
    print(x)
except NameError:
    print("error!")

error!
```

It will print "error!" IF anything in the `try:` block resulted in a NameError.

You can also use "else" and "finally" for more control.
Any code in the Else block runs if there were no errors.

```
try:
  print("Hello")
except:
  print("Something went wrong")
else:
  print("Nothing went wrong")

Hello
Nothing went wrong
```

Anything in a "finally" block runs after regardless of if there was an error or not.

```
try:
  print(x)
except:
  print("Something went wrong")
finally:
  print("The 'try except' is finished")

Something went wrong
The 'try except' is finished
```

I recommend reading the W3 Schools page on Try Except.
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp

Protip: you can do something like `except Exception as e` which will save info about the exception to `e`.